# Powershell get-netadapter differs frrom get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to query for **physical** network adapters and I see different result from different approaches

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter  -Filter "NetEnabled='True' and  PhysicalAdapter='True'"| select netconnectionid, name, netconnecionstatus
```

returns

[image: get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter]

whereas

```
get-netadapter -physical
```

returns only

[image]

I was under the assumption that `-physical` is same as `PhysicalAdapter='True'` but that don't seem to be the case as seen from the results. why?

Comment: I think virtual networks are not recognized as `physical` by one, and not by another.

Answer (score 1):

The cmdlets return different data types:

```
[PS]> (Get-NetAdapter -Physical).GetType().FullName
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance

[PS]> (Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_NetworkAdapter").GetType().FullName
System.Object[]

[PS]> (Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_NetworkAdapter")[0].GetType().FullName
System.Management.ManagementObject
```

I'm not sure I can do the CimInstance-vs-WMI discussion any justice here, so you might want to start with reading these blogs:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/04/14/comparing-cim-and-wmi-in-powershell/
- https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/wmi-and-cim/

The cmdlets might be doing different things under the hood, but this doesn't necessarily explain why you see *more* interfaces using one method. It might simply be that some of the interfaces returned by `Get-WMIObject` are "hidden" interfaces. Note that `Get-NetAdapter` supports the `-IncludeHidden` switch.

> [Get-NetAdapter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867.aspx)
>
> The Get-NetAdapter cmdlet gets the basic network adapter properties.
>   By default only visible adapters are returned.

Comment: It is not hidden. I think, it is because virtual Ethernet adapters are not exposed thru Powershell but it does thru the `win32` api

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have Windows 8/2012 installed I can't verify the exact xml used for Get-NetAdapter I can't post it here but what is it probably doing is following a default formatting template for that cmdlet.

It's basically a XML file that decides what properties to display and how to format them.

The WMI object dose not have any as its not a product of a direct cmdlet, its just pulling informations from the wmi class.

Comment: The question is not about formatting; it is about the results. 'Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205' is the only physical adapter, but why does `win32_networkadapter` show 3 other results which as just logical. Sorry for not being clear. I have updated the question.

Comment: So Get-NetAdapter -Physical is only displaying the physical adapters. Maybe -Physical acts as a filter? It sounds like your asking why the wmi class gives you all adapter whereas the cmdlet gives you the filtered results? Or not? :)

Comment: yes. -physical is a filter and so is PhysicalAdapter='True'. The question is why aren't they returning the same value